# $C_{c}(T)=C_{0}(T)=C(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $T=\{1, 2,\cdots\}\cup \{\infty \} $. For $n, m=1, 2, \cdots$, define

$$d(n,m)=\left\vert \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \right\vert,\quad d(n, \infty)=\frac{1}{n}=d(\infty, m), d(\infty, \infty)=0$$ and under that metric $T$  is compact (How?) and for that

$$C_{c}(T)=C_{0}(T)=C(T)$$

How?

My thought: Can we define an isometric between $\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\cdots \} \cup \{0\}$ to $T$.

Comment: What is $C_0(T)$?

Comment: continuous function vanishing at $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $T$ and $\{0\}\cup\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\right\}$ are isometric. Just consider the map $f\colon T\longrightarrow\{0\}\cup\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\right\}$ such that $f(\infty)=0$ and that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f(n)=\frac1n$. Therefore, $T$ is compact, since $\{0\}\cup\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\right\}$ is compact.

However, $C(T)\neq C_0(T)$, since $1\in C(T)\setminus C_0(T)$.

Comment: Yes, but how can I show the equality in the OP.

Comment: @1256 You can't. See the line that I added.

Comment: @1256 Then your book is wrong. Not my fault. I didn't write it.